# Help on ODE - what is the technique?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$xy^2 + 3y^2 - x^2y' = 0$$
> and
> $$2xy^3 + e^x + (3x^2y^2 + \sin y)y' = 0$$

I am given two problems. I have learned how to do integrating factors on linear equations and how to separate variables in non-linear equations. But I can't figure out how to apply either technique to the problems. Can anyone help me understand how to set these up? Or am I missing some technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$xy^2 +3y^2 -x^2 y' =0\Leftrightarrow 1+\frac{3}{x} =\frac{y'}{y}\Leftrightarrow 1+\frac{3}{x}=(\ln y)'\Leftrightarrow C+x+3\ln x =\ln y$$

The second equation you can write as
$$(2xy^3+e^x) dx +(3x^2 y^2 +\sin y ) dy =0$$
and since $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} (3x^2 y^2 +\sin y )=\frac{\partial }{\partial y} (2xy^3+e^x)$$ there exists a function $F$ such that
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=3x^2 y^2 +\sin y $$
hence $$F(x,y)=x^2 y^3 -\cos y +g(x)$$ thus
$$g'(x) =e^x $$ and the solution is given by $$x^2 y^3 -\cos y +e^x +C=0$$

Answer (score 1):

For the first ODE, we have $$ \dfrac{x+3}{x^{2}} = \dfrac{y^{\prime}}{y^{2}},$$ which can be solved very easily by integrating from both sides.

The second is an exact ODE. In fact we have:

$\dfrac{d}{dy}(2xy^{3} + e^{x}) = 6xy^{2}$,

and,

$\dfrac{d}{dx}(3x^{2}y^{2} + \sin{y}) = 6xy^{2}$.

Can you finish it now?

> Here, the answer for the ODE is $x^{2}y^{3} + e^{x} -\cos(y) = C$, where $C$ is some constant.

Comment: Thanks helpful. On your exact ODE, I could use some more help, tbh. In doing exact ODEs, why do you just take the partials of, for example in the second partial, the long parenthetical with 3x and sin y etc. And in the first partial, you just looked at the first two terms. What have I forgotten from MV Calculus?

Comment: @Abcderia See this link for example. https://www.math24.net/exact-differential-equations

Comment: I appreciate this explanation enormously. One last question and it is why I was confused on the exact ODE. I didn't know you could rewrite those first terms with a "dx" after them. Most problems I've worked have the dx in them. I didn't recognize that here. Can you help me understand how you can collect those two loose terms at the beginning and make them a phrase with dx attached?